# Finding out which outgoing port needs to be opened

Tags: firewall, port

I've got an application that used to work perfectly with all outgoing ports open and all incoming ports closed. Now we've closed all outgoing ports except a few specific ones e.g. http and it's not working any more. Is there a way I can find out using tools like wireshark which outgoing request is getting blocked so I can tell my sysadmin what to open?

Comment: I should mention I tried looking at vendor documentation, etc.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the vendor's support to *ask* which ports are used?

Comment: Have you tried using netstat to show you which ports?

Answer (score 3):

It should be listed in your firewall's log. If you don't log blocked outgoing traffic, turn this on at least until you know what to open.

Comment: +1, Wireshark will also show TCP SYN packets trying to open the connection and should have the destination port listed there too.

Answer (score 1):

Use this app http://www.netlimiter.com/ and it will list out all the connections/ports/addresses that any app running is using.